# mat-table filtering using mat select in angular

Tags: angular

```
<mat-select #captionlist (selectionChange)="filterByProducts($event)">
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let p of list_product.data" [value]="p">
        {{ p.description }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
              
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="ltb" matSort style="width: 100%;"> 
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id" style="width: 20%;">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center 
                               !important;" mat-sort-header> id </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let list_brands" style="text-align: center;"> 
                             {{list_brands.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>
  </table>
```

type script code is :

export class BasicComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

```
  public list_product = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
  public list_brands = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);

filter(filtervalue: any)
          {
           this.list_brands.filterPredicate = 
        (data, filter: string) => data.CaptionCode== filtervalue.value.id;
          this.list_brands.filter=filtervalue.value.id;
          }
```

This code used to work but I do not know why it does not work now

Comment: Can you share sample data for `list_product.data` and `ltb` to the question?

Comment: code edited for help

Comment: This code had no problems before and it worked properly

Comment: Please revise your code. `event` variable doesn't exist in `filter` method. And `filterByProducts` method doesn't exist in `BasicComponent`.

Comment: Can you create a working sample in stackblitz?

Comment: excuse me i rename some variable event=filtervalue